# TypeScript error: Type 'IStory | undefined' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript

I'm using dynamic routing. I get id: string with useParams then I loop through array of posts to find target post and change type of id to Number otherwise I get an error. The problem happens when I assign type IStory to targetStory. It says:

> Type 'IStory | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IStory'.   Type
> 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IStory'.

I do not know how to fix that. Could you help me please?

```
interface IStoryPageProps {
  id: string;
}

export interface IStory {
    by: string;
    descendants: number;
    id: number;
    kids: number[];
    score: number;
    time: number;
    date: string;
    title: string;
    type: string;
    url: string;
  }
  
const StoryPage: React.FC = () => {
  const { id } = useParams<IStoryPageProps>();

  const { storyList } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.story);

  // error happens here
  const targetStory: IStory = storyList.find((story) => story.id === Number(id));

  return (
    <section>
      <BackButton />
      <h1></h1>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's because [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?retiredLocale=vi) could possibly return `undefined` if it fails to find any item**

You could have a `fallback` to your find condition and cast it like so:

```
const targetStory: IStory = storyList.find((story) => story.id === Number(id)) {} as IStory;
```

Comment: I'm newbie to TS. I tried your solution but the error remains: Type 'IStory | {}' is not assignable to type 'IStory'. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IStory': by, descendants, id, kids, and 6 more.

Comment: Hey, I actually missing `cast` type. Updated my answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: Try to use `storyList.find((story) => story.id === Number(id)) || []`. Personally, I don't like using `find`. It produces a lot of conditional statements/expressions

Comment: Great suggestion, But still got `Type 'never[]' is missing`. The `IStory` was an object.